# remove <a> and return its text only from html line with specific language with Regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove `<a>` tags for lines which include a specific sentence as follows:

```
text before line im interested in which may include <a> tag </a>
Go to <a href="#step2"> Step 2</a>
text after line im intrested in which may also include <a> tag </a>
```

so far what I came up with:

```
(?!(Go to|Return to|Continue to)( )?)(<a(.*)?>(?!(( )?Step \d( )?))(.*)?<\/a>)|(<a.*(Go to|Return to|Continue to).*\/a>)
```

but this doesn't seem to get me what I need :-( `<a> tag </a>`

desired result: `Go to Step 2`

What am I missing?

Comment: You can you jsoup library which does the parsing for you.

Comment: I already use BeautifulSoup to scrape and parse

Comment: Python/JS, yes I want Go to Step 2 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe this expression might be close to what you might have in mind, not sure though.

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"(go\s+to|return\s+to|continue\s+to)\s*<a\s+(?:[^>]+?)>([^<]+?)\s*</a>"

test_str = ("text before line im interested in which may include <a> tag </a>\n"
    "Go to <a href=\"#step2\"> Step 2</a>\n"
    "Return to <a href=\"#step2\"> Step 20 </a>\n"
    "CONTINUE To      <a href=\"#step2\"> Step 20   </a>\n"
    "text after line im intrested in which may also include <a> tag </a>")

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE)

for match in matches:
    print(match[0]+match[1])
```

#### Output

```
Go to Step 2
Return to Step 20
CONTINUE To Step 20
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/2z2QZE/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
(Go to|Return to|Continue to)\s*<a[^>]*>\s*(Step \d+)
```

Which will capture the "Go to" in match 1 and "Step 2" in match 2. Then concatenate them for your desired output.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/l1Wvi1/1/)

Comment: it actually capture Go to <a href="#step2"> Step 2

Comment: No it *matches* that, but it *captures* what is in the parentheses as Capture Group 1 and Capture Group 2

Comment: In python that would be `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)`

Comment: not sure what you are testing your regex with, but in https://regexr.com/ your solution selects the whole thing as I mentioned above not as groups.

Comment: I can assure you that the parts of the regular expression in (...) are captured into groups. That is their primary purpose in a regular expression. I entered it into regexr.com and if you hover over the highlighted match it will show you that Group #1 contains "Go to" and Group #2 contains "Step 2".

Comment: Thanks @Emma for adding the link to the demo!